# Can i render a view while task currently executing?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Let's imagine I have this view in views.py:

```
def wait_and_print(request):      
      print(5)  
      time.sleep(90)  
      return render(request, 'view.html')
```

I want to display view.html before the time.sleep(90) task completes (leaving it to execute in background as it is not necessary for my view). I've read about synchro-asynchro tasks but I can't seem to understand quite well how to perform this operation.

Thanks,

Comment: No. Every statement is done in turn. If you want to perform background tasks, you need solutions like [Dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io/index.html), [Django RQ](https://python-rq.org/) or the often quoted, but very bloated and increasingly unreliable [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/). It can also be done when running in ASGI mode, since Django 3.0, but if you cannot wrap your head around async code, the learning curve is quite steep. You could start with [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/).

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant to link [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-async-features/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding an AJAX function under `view.html` pointing to an URL that render an empty HTTP response:
the URL `/run_ajax` (which should be included in your `urls.py`) should be like this:

````
```re_path(r'^run_ajax', views.function_to_call_with_ajax)```
````

the function_to_call_with_ajax is this (in view.py):

```
def wait_and_print(request):      
  print(5)  
  time.sleep(90)  
  return HttpResponse("")
```

AJAX function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/run_ajax', //The URL you defined in urls.py
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('data ', data)

            //If you wish you can do additional data manipulation here.
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('error', error)
        }

    });
```